# How to enable a button if in a group of checkboxes at least one checkbox is checked in Angular (14+)?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, forms

I have a group of checkboxes and I want to disable the submit button if none of the checkboxes is checked, if instead at least 1 of the list of checkboxes is checked I want to activate the submit button. What's the easiest way to do this?

**In HTML:**

```
<form [formGroup]="driverForm " (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">

    <div formGroupName="categoryLicense">
        <label for="A1">A1</label>
        <input id="A1" type="checkbox" formControlName="A1" (input)="setSubmit($event)" />
    
        <label for="A2">A2</label>
        <input id="A2" type="checkbox" formControlName="A2" (input)="setSubmit($event)" />
    
        <label for="A">A</label>
        <input id="A" type="checkbox" formControlName="A" (input)="setSubmit($event)" />
    
        //Others inputs...
    </div>

 <button type="submit" [disabled]="!checkboxSelected">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**In TypeScript:**

```
checkboxSelected = false;


driverForm = new FormGroup({
    // Others variables..
    categoryLicense: new FormGroup({
      A1: new FormControl(false),
      A2: new FormControl(false),
      A: new FormControl(false),
      B1: new FormControl(false),
      B: new FormControl(false),
      BE: new FormControl(false),
      C1: new FormControl(false),
      C1E: new FormControl(false),
      C: new FormControl(false),
      CE: new FormControl(false),
      D1: new FormControl(false),
      D1E: new FormControl(false),
      D: new FormControl(false),
      DE: new FormControl(false),
    }),
 });

setSubmit(e: any) {
    
    // code to implement
 }
```

I think I could use validators, but I'm not quite sure how to use them in a context like this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use validators to do this check.

Your validator could look something like:

```
const oneCheckedValidator = (): ValidatorFn => 
(formGroup: FormGroup): ValidationErrors | null => {
      const formControls = Object.keys(formGroup.controls)
    
      for (const c of formControls) {
        if(formGroup.get(c).value) {
          return null;
        }
      }
    
      return { ['SomeErrorCode']: true };
    };
```

Then on your form group's definition:

```
driverForm = new FormGroup({
    // Others variables..
    categoryLicense: new FormGroup({
      A1: new FormControl(false),
      A2: new FormControl(false),
      A: new FormControl(false),
      B1: new FormControl(false),
      B: new FormControl(false),
      BE: new FormControl(false),
      C1: new FormControl(false),
      C1E: new FormControl(false),
      C: new FormControl(false),
      CE: new FormControl(false),
      D1: new FormControl(false),
      D1E: new FormControl(false),
      D: new FormControl(false),
      DE: new FormControl(false),
    }, oneCheckedValidator()),
 });
```

Then there are a few ways you could check whether your FormGroup is valid. You can check either the invalid or valid properties of the FormGroup object or you can check if it has any errors via the errors property or hasErrors() function.